# Launching an app from Android Wear screen

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a Samsung device that I'm using to get an understanding of how wear works. So in using Hangouts Hangouts, Gmail etc, I see that I can respond to messages depending on what the app supports.  I also see that some of the notifications have the ability to launch the app on the phone. Is this something that is built into the API? Or is this something special in the notification to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to launch the app on the phone is automatically added to the notification of the wearable device as soon as you define a *[Pending Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)*.

**Example:**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent mPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);
// …
```

If you want to add additional actions to the notification you can add them basically in the same way as the *ContentIntent*:

**Example:**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .addAction(ICON,
                TEXT, INTENT);
//…
```

If you want that the action only appears on the wearable, you have to use the *[WearableExtender](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.WearableExtender.html)*.

**Example:**

```
NotificationCompat.Action action =
        new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(ICON,
                TEXT, INTENT)
                .build();

Notification notification =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .extend(new WearableExtender().addAction(action));

// …
```

You can read, basically everything I’ve just said, on the following Android-Developer page again (and explained in even more detail): [Click](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html)